# Don't clear textbox value after an error has been occurred

Tags: php, forms

I wish that after I sent the data, if an error occurs it does not delete data already written in textboxes or checkboxes. How can I do that?
This is html code:

```
<form action="adaugare-elev.php?actiune=validare" method="post">
    Date de contact <br>
    <table>
       <tr><td>Nume: <th><input type="text" name="nume" required></th></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Prenume: <th><input type="text" name="prenume" required></th></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Seria: <input type="text" style="width:25px;" name="seria" required></td> <td>Nr: <input type="text" name="nr" style="width:50px;" name="nr" required></td></tr>
       <tr><td>CNP: <th><input type="text" name="cnp" required></th></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Mail: <th><input type="text" name="mail" required></th></td></tr>
       <tr><td>Loc de munca: <th><input type="text" name="locmunca" required></th></td></tr>
    </table><br>
</form>
```

This is php code for form:

```
if(!isset($_GET['actiune'])) 
    $_GET['actiune'] = '';
switch($_GET['actiune'])
{
    case 'validare':
       $_SESSION['nume'] = $_POST['nume'];
       $_SESSION['prenume'] = $_POST['prenume'];
       $_SESSION['seria'] = $_POST['seria'];
       $_SESSION['nr'] = $_POST['nr'];
       $_SESSION['cnp'] = $_POST['cnp'];
       $_SESSION['mail'] = $_POST['mail'];
       $_SESSION['locmunca'] = $_POST['locmunca'];
       $inserare = "insert into `elevi` (`nume`,`prenume`,`nr`,`cnp`,`mail`,`locmunca`,) values ('".addentities($_SESSION['nume'])."','".addentities($_SESSION['prenume'])."','".addentities($_SESSION['nr'])."','".addentities($_SESSION['cnp'])."','".addentities($_SESSION['mail'])."','".addentities($_SESSION['locmunca'])."')";
}
```

I tried so use a pop-up `alert (echo "<script>alert('Something's wrong')</script>";` after an if clause) but it didn't worked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a server sided language and to keep your data, you should save your values into a session to keep them. if you want to prevent users from leaving fields empty, use javascript.

You should add a check to see if there is a `mysql_error()` or if you're using mysqli; `mysqli_error()`. If there is one, echo the values in your form. Add a small check in the form to see if a session is filled. Can be achieved by this:

```
if ( isset ( $_SESSION['error'] ) ) {
    // echo the form with the values in there
}
```

if you want to do it easier but on a dirty way, use something like this;

```
<tr><td>Nume: <th><input type="text" name="nume" value="<?php ( ( isset ( $_SESSION['error'] ) ) ? echo $_SESSION['nume'] : "" ) ?>" required></th></td></tr>
```

Make sure to set the `$_SESSION['error']` to something when the `mysql_error()` returns an error.

But since it's a POST, you can also echo the $_POST["nume"] in the value.

---

To fill in the `$_SESSION['error']` you first need to add a check if your `$inserare` is being executed in the right way. To do so, you have to request the errors for the right mysql version you use.

I don't know what variable you're using for your result, **so change this to your variable!**

```
$query = mysql_query($inserare);
```

mysqli:

```
if ( mysql_error ( $query ) ) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 1;
}
```

mysql:

```
if ( mysqli_error ( $query ) ) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: There's something wrong in the script and I couldn't find it.. required is canceled and it says that: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO`

Comment: Oh oops, try it without the `echo` in `echo $_SESSION['nume']` and replace the `<?php` to `<?=`

Comment: Still not working..Script is working but the value is not shown

Comment: did you set the `$_SESSION['error'] = 1` when `mysql_error()` returns something?

Comment: not really..how do I do that? or where should I put that?

Comment: I don't know why but it still doesn't work, I keep modified the code but for  nothing..That's it, if you find the solution I will be grateful, but otherwise, I'll use other solution..I liked the idea of using error sesion..

Comment: Sorry to have bothered you, thank you for everthing :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Too bad that we can't find the solution for this. The isset($_POST["name"]) would work too. It's the same concept.

Comment: Anyway, I think that the problem is at `$_POST['nume'] (or $_SESSION['nume'])` because the first version was fine, except those `""` after `:`..I tried to change them into `' '` but with no succes..As I already sad, because of that, required was canceled, the code seems to be incomplete, not actually wrong

Comment: I misplaced the echo, I think that's all haha.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check, is the post data was set or not, and if yes, then set it as a value of the input. For example:

```
<tr><td>Nume: <th><input type="text" name="nume" value="<?php if (!empty($_POST["nume"])) { echo $_POST["nume"]; } else { echo ''; };  ?>" required></th></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

or in addition to lolka_bolka's post use an tertiary operator

```
<tr><td>Nume: <th><input type="text" name="nume" value="<?= !empty($_POST["nume"]) ?$_POST["nume"] : ''   ?>" required></th></td></tr>
```

Comment: You should echo the value, else it'll do nothing to the $_POST["nume"].

Comment: it will echo because i use php5 short tag: "<?=" (means <?php echo)